# How can I get the sheetname by passing the sheetid? QlikSense API

Tags: qliksense

I have list of sheet ids in an app using the getAllInfos() method. I would like to find the sheet name. How can i get the sheet name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
You first get the object from the doc and then use getlayout on the result